# No puedo cargar una imagen para mi aplicación de Facebook

Tags: aplicación-web, facebook, permisos, facebook-api

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Qué tal, buenas tardes. No sé si alguno pueda ayudarme con el siguiente problema:

Resulta que estoy desarrollando un Chatbot para FB Messenger, para ello utilizó la página de FB Developers para, entre otras cosas, configurar ciertas características internas de mi aplicación.

Uno de los pasos finales consiste en que se debe de generar una solicitud de revisión de la aplicación, para que pueda ser utilizada por cualquier usuario dentro de Facebook.

Una de las características que necesitas para que tu solicitud de revisión pueda ser enviada, es que tu aplicación necesita una imagen, algún ícono con el que pueda ser identificada. Por lo tanto, si no se cuenta con dicha imagen, es imposible enviar la solicitud de revisión.

Aquí el problema está en que, al momento de ingresar la imagen, no aparece ningún botón o ícono de confirmación que me diga que la imagen se haya subido, y al momento de guardar cambios, me sigue indicando que falta ingresar una imagen. ¿Alguno de ustedes sabe a qué se debe?

Adjunto las imágenes de los recuadros de carga. [image: Recuadro que me indica que necesito ingresarle un ícono a la aplicación[![Recuadro de carga de la imagen]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ltx7e.png)

Después de subir el ícono, el último recuadro me sigue apareciendo, sin ningún botón de confirmación ni nada por el estilo. ¿Cómo se puede solucionar este problema? Ya intenté haciendo el mismo procedimiento en Ubuntu y ocurre lo mismo.

Comment: verifica que la imagen cuenta con las medidas exactas, ya que por un simple pixel demás este no carga la imagen, debe ser exacta a 1024x1024

Comment: Me sucede exactamente lo mismo, la imagen mide exactamente 1024X1024 y no me permite subirla.
Por favor, compartéme tu solucion si logras encontrarla, al igual seguire investigando y te comparto lo que encuentre